# Delete particular data from Json url using android

Tags: java, php, javascript, android, jquery

I have get muliple data from Json url using android.but i need to delete Particular data in json url using android.how to delete specific data from json url?.

Comment: I think ur Application in Phonegap. If you have Php webService, you can Directly call the WebService thougrh PhoneGAp also normal android application.

Comment: What you have to tried so far, can you show some code.

Comment: delete specific data from JSON URL? If you include more detail for the question then you would get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you can directly delete server data. Try to do some PHP code for that and you can invoke it from android.ie, you can separate functions by adding arguments in http request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sure what you're trying to remove, if some data from the URL, or from the response. Anyway, if you know the exact string you're trying to remove, you could use the method replaceAll(String) from the String class.

For example:

```
String finalUrl = url.replaceAll("/partof/theurl/", "");
```

Hope this helps you.